# How to set paper feed size in thermal pos printer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, printing

i have a question that how to adjust the paper feed size settings on a POS 80 thermal printer?

I don't want extra space at the end of the printed page. To ensure that there is no extra space added at the end of the page, i have tried to adjust the CSS. i had set the body and HTML height to 100%, which i thought it should help remove any unwanted space at the end of the page but it is not working. so in code it is not working is there any setting in which i can perform in my computer device's printer setting to set the custom paper feed size. Give me solution for that. the CSS i have tried is this

`@page { size: 74mm 105mm; /* Set your custom paper size, e.g., A7 size */ margin: 0; }`